# Настройка Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu

Команда в ubuntu: 'java --version' дает такой результат - Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:...
В тоже самое время, аналогичная команда для PowerShell дает такой - openjdk 18.0.2.1 2022-08-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.2.1+1-1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.2.1+1-1, mixed mode, sharing).

Переменные окружения настроены. Подскажите пожалуйста направление мысли.

Comment: Это значит в Windows java машина установлена, а в Ubuntu не установлена.

Comment: Запускайте программу из текущей директории.

Comment: `sudo apt install default-jre` или с сайта скачайте